# Flexbox not wraping and child percentage width not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a grid with 2 rows and 3 columns using flexbox.

So, inside my layout, I set a parent div as display:flex and setted flex-wrap:wrap to get the second row.

Then I decided to set the children's width as 30% (expecting each child would get 30% of parents. In this situation, my box should appear with 3 itens per row.

But this is now working!

Here is my code:

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/q39zj6j2/13/

And the CSS:

```
#destaquesHome {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap:wrap;
margin:0px 0 0 0px;
}

.destaquesHome-item {
width: 32%;
display: table;
margin:10px 0 0 0px;
height:100px;    
border:1px solid #C8C8C8;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you inheriting the `a` element `width` not `#destaquesHome`, `.destaquesHome-item` inside `a` element that's why it is taking width 32% of `a` element. Try following way:

```
#destaquesHome > a {
  min-width:32%;
  display: block;
}

.destaquesHome-item {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin:10px 0 0 0px;
  height:100px;    
  border:1px solid #C8C8C8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;   
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!